# Pyspark Conda saveAsTextFile File Already Exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, conda

I am running a spark-submit job using a customized conda environment. I managed to ship out the conda environment using yarn and it had no problem running. However, it always fails at the very last step when I tried to saveAsTextFile. I ensured the path was empty before I ran the job but somehow it got created after I kicked off the job and there is a temporary folder there afterwards.

The method is pretty much following [this blog](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Running-PySpark-with-Conda-Env/ta-p/247551) and the script.py itself is not complex at all, everything works (read file, count) by printing to stdout and I can read it from executor logs, but not savingAsTextFile.

All the other executors did not even start due to this error. I am assuming the driver will create this folder, create the temporary/flag file indicating it is work in progress, and all the executors will divide and conquer by saving temporary output somewhere which later added to this folder. After all, the temporary flag will be deleted indicating the job finished.

This is how I kicked off my job:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./${CONDAENV}/bin/python3 \
/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/bin/spark-submit  \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2 \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.YARN_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf \
--num-executors 4 \
--archives py36yarn.zip#PY_ENV \
--executor-memory 4G \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./PY_ENV/py36yarn/bin/python3 \
script.py
```

This is the error message:

```
script.py", line 50, in main
    res.saveAsTextFile(filename_output)
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1552, in saveAsTextFile
    keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://ddsco-nameservice/user/yolo/arrowcom_result already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:131)
   ....
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The file that blocks:

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://ddsco-nameservice/user/yolo/arrowcom_result/
Found 1 items
drwxrwxr-x+  - a59347 users          0 2020-03-19 10:18 hdfs://ddsco-nameservice/user/yolo/arrowcom_result/_temporary
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have missed "/" at the end of your output path.

**Explanation:**

This is the standard behaviour while writing files, two step process where all the
intermediated results will be written to a directory (by default created within your output path with _temporary prefix for spark and later renamed/moved to match the output path.

If the path already exists, spark will raise exception even before generating _temporary files, that can be handled by save.mode('overwrite').

You can change the path to the temp folder for each Spark application by spark.local.dir property to some other location